# Downloading a specific dependency .jar file in a dynamic directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, lombok

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This configuration in `pom.xml` basically downloads all the depedencies .jar files in target/lib directory that can be found in our project folder.

However, I only want to download a specific dependency .jar file to that folder. Is there a way to do that?

The dependency I am trying to filter is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#includeArtifactIds)?

Comment: First question: Why do you like to do that?

Comment: @khmarbaise - To bypass SonarQube scan on classes that uses Lombok annotations. Classes that uses Lombok annotations are being flagged as code smells. I have a configuration to point out the lombok.jar to bypass the scan. So yea, I need a dynamic configuration to be able to pass the build in Jenkins. Though I have figured it out already. 

Comment: That does not make sense. So configure SonarQube to ignore such things or don't use lombok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the appropriate configuration on how to do it incase someone has to do this also in the future:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```